# Jquery code disabled the hyperlink on image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5MRL/
I use jquery to make a image pop out when user click on a transparent div.And the image is supposed to be a hyperlink to an url. But there is no hyperlink after the image pop out.What's the problem?

HTML

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com/"><img id="enterout4" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSRDwuNVz5koLf3uGVSWt_otiZsKwCVAQK8gb0ppY3GFULHEU0C2w"></a>
```

Jquery

```
 $('#enter4').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#enterout4').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#enterout4').width($(window).width()/4.6);
    console.log();
});

$('#enter4').mouseleave(function(){

    $('#enterout4').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

css:

```
#enter4{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9999;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   top: 0%;
   left: 0%;
   opacity: 0;
}

#enterout4{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0%;
   left: 0%;
   z-index: 9998;
   display: none;
   height:auto;
}
```

Here is the example
http://jsfiddle.net/Y5MRL/

Comment: where is `#enter4`, and why use `jQuery 1.9.1`, `Migrate 1.1.0`
`jQuery UI 1.9.2`, `jQuery Mobile 1.3.0b1` and `jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 `at the same time? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example is incomplete but I guess you wandered why after the fade effect you cannot click anything anymore. This is because the fadeOut() method also sets the display to none.

You should than use the animate() method to do the fade with setting the opacity to zero and vice versa.

I added for debugging a background color to the div to see the clickable area.

```
$('#enterout4')
.css({ opacity: 0 })
.hide();
$('#enter4').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#enterout4').show();
    $('#enterout4')
    .animate({opacity: 1, width: $(window).width()/4.6,}, 1500);  
});

$('#enter4').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#enterout4').animate({ opacity: 0, duration: 1500 });
});
```

See the improved js fiddle using animate for both width and opacity.
Edit: I think I got it now. You have a div with id enter4.
http://jsfiddle.net/P5j5m/22/